# BCL type that implements two instances of the same generic type

Tags: .net, generics, msdn, base-class-library

Do any classes in the .NET framework, or any other library documented in the MSDN library, explicitly implement two instantiations of the same generic interface?

For example, the following class explicitly implements both `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<string>`.

```
public class T : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<string>
{
    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

For anyone wondering, I'm working on addressing issues with Sandcastle Help File Builder failing to resolve the MSDN documentation URLs for inherited explicitly implemented interface methods. For example, classes which extend `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` inherit the explicit implementation of `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>)`. When using MTPS to look up this method, the contentIdentifier is the following:

> AssetId:M:System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System#Collections#Generic#ICollection{**T**}#Contains(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair{`0,`1})

If you note the bold **T** in there, you'll see that this syntax would not be able to distinguish between the specific case I am asking about above. By locating an existing class in the framework, I can use the MTPS service to examine the content identifiers being used in the case of this particular type of conflict, allowing me to ensure correct behavior for this surely rare but theoretically possible edge case.

Comment: I believe the answer to your underlying question is `M:T.System#Collections#Generic#IEnumerable{System#Int32}#GetEnumerator` and `M:T.System#Collections#Generic#IEnumerable{System#String}#GetEnumerator`

Comment: This won't help you, but  http://dotnetinside.com/en/framework/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Build/RetrievableEntryHashSet%601

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.propertymaxlengthconvention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`System.Workflow.Activities.ReceiveActivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.receiveactivity) implements both `IActivityEventListener<ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs>` and `IActivityEventListener<QueueEventArgs>`.
- [`System.Net.PeerToPeer.Collaboration.PeerNearMe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer.collaboration.peernearme) and `PeerContact` each implement two different `IEquatable<T>`s (via the base `Peer` class)
- [`System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryNodeSequence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.runtime.xmlquerynodesequence) implements `IList<XPathItem>` and `IList<XPathNavigator>`

Comment: In each of those cases, the explicit interface implementations are actually on different types, not the same type.

Comment: EF has three types that do implement multiple interface parameterizations directly.   `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.SqlCePropertyMaxLengthConvention`, `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PropertyMaxLengthConvention`, `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.SqlCePropertyMaxLengthConvention`

Comment: In *those* cases, the parameter types of the different overloads distinguish the methods. However, based on this I realized that the issue I'm trying to prevent could only affect code linking to *MSDN documentation*, so if no MSDN documentation has these characteristics then it really couldn't ever be a bug!